# facebook API throttle budget

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Anyone know what is the facebook api throttle budget. In their insights, they tell you when you surpass their so-called budget, but they don't say what the budget is??
We have a canvas app in RoR that is being throttled at times, and in order to manage it yet maintain efficiency, we need to know what their budget is.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't announced or documented any throttling for Graph API requests.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find any too. However, maybe someone has managed to measure it, or know the ball park?